# Unable to download npm module

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules

Unable to download npm module because of error

> An unexpected error occurred: 
>   "https://registry.npmjs.com/react-redux: connect ETIMEDOUT
>   104.16.17.35:443". info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in
>   "C:\Users\obioh\Desktop\React\teat-app\yarn-error.log".

How to resolve it?

Comment: Are you using proxy server?

Comment: I am able to visit that address. It looks like a bunch of JSON.